# Jquery dialog null-ing model properties in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog

I'm using a jquery popup/dialog in an mvc application, but after i've had the dialog opened, if i make a post request all data in my model is null.

i'm opening the dialog like this

```
$(".mybutton").bind("click", function (event) {
  var dialogOpts = {
            modal: true, autoOpen: false, width: 400, height: 200, hide: { effect: "puff", duration: 200 }
        };

        $("#popupdiv").dialog(dialogOpts);
        $("#popupdiv").dialog("open");
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    });
```

i pinpointed the null-ing of my data to when dialog(dialogOpts) is called. even if i call it without calling dialog("open") the data in my model is null, though the dialog was never opened.

the popup div is a simple div with some html elements in it.

i cannot figure out how and why this happens.

Comment: Can you please show more code

Comment: I guess you got the same issue which I just answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396880/access-variables-inside-jquery-dialog/22398092#22398092

Answer (score 0):

Try This One use jquery css and js

```
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit Date": function () {
                        // ajax passing
                        $(this).dialog("close");                            
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Getting same result with this approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 339,
                overlay: {
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    opacity: 0.5
                },
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 500
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 700
                }
            });
        });

        function OpenDialog()
        {
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");
        }
    </script>

    <div id="open" onclick="OpenDialog();">Click To Open</div>  

        <div id="dialog">   
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
        {
            // Popup content
        }
        </div>
```

Comment: Getting same result with this approach